# configure the php.ini on vagrant homestead

Tags: php, vagrant, homestead, php-shorttags

I want to allow short_open_tags in php.ini

I want to access to the php.ini on my vagrant box configured with homestead.
I saw the php.ini file in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

But ... permission denied
Is somebody knows ?

Thanks

Comment: Did MartinJH answer your question?

Answer (score 51):

Here is how you grant read/write access to php.ini, modify it, save changes & reload nginx:

**1.** Navigate to folder containing php.ini: `$ cd /etc/php5/fpm`

**2.** Grant read/write access: `$ sudo chmod -R ugo+rw php.ini`

**3.** Open php.ini: `$ vim php.ini`

**4.** Enter edit mode: `$ i`

**5.** Edit stuff

**6.** Exit edit mode: Press ESC

**7.** Save & close php.ini: `$ :x!`

**7.1** OPTIONAL: Exit without saving: `$ :q`

**8.** Navigate to home (not sure if this is actually necessary): `$ cd ~`

**9.** Reload/Restart nginx: `$ sudo nginx -s reload`

**10.1** Reload/Restart php: `$ sudo service php5-fpm restart`

**10.2** If using PHP 7 then use `$ sudo service php7.0-fpm restart` (Thanks & Credit to Richard in comments).

**11.** ???

**12.** PROFIT! (or is that joke really too old?)

Here is a screenshot:

[image: git bash showing php.ini before & after getting read/write access]

Remember if you run `$ vagrant provision`, it'll reset all configuration files. Just so you know.

**EDIT**

Super useful to know. [You can search in vim](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/help/vim/searching.html) by exiting input mode, and type `$ /post_max_size` or whatever you want to find.

Comment: In php.ini the last value takes precedence so a one-liner should be: sudo su; echo "short_open_tag = On" >> /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini; service restart php5-fpm; exit;

Comment: If using PHP 7 then use `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`

Comment: The trick was ``sudo service php7.0-fpm restart``, I was editing the right file but I was restarting nginx instead of php fpm

Comment: `sudo service php7.1-fpm restart` for php7.1, hopefully the pattern is clear now

Comment: `service --status-all` when in doubt. Somewhere in the list is a service starting with `php`

Comment: Run `readlink -f "$(which php)"` or `php -v` to determine which version of php you are using. Looks like the directory structure has changed a bit too: now, you need to `cd /etc/php/x.x/fpm` where `x.x` is your php version.

Comment: To see the path where your **php.ini** file is located you can run `php --ini`. This will show which php.ini file is being read

Answer (score 11):

Just create ".user.ini" file ([.user.ini files](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)) in public/

```
[PHP]
short_open_tag = On
```

Comment: I forgot the [PHP] and didn't know it was obligated.

Comment: Thanks, Simple answer!

Comment: Simple and straightforward solution. Also nice, because does not depend on specific php version and does not need changes to the provisioning. The file can be created by any means and will be effective within vagrant. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

Simply ssh in to the homestead environment:

```
ssh homestead
```

Then become the superuser by typing:

```
sudo su
```

Then you will be able to edit your php.ini.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to change the mentioned php.ini for over an hour.
I suggest to check first which `php.ini` is really loaded.
I have checked it with `php -i`.

In my case it was located in `/etc/php/7.2/cli`.

Comment: Adding a grep command to this `php -i | grep php.ini` shows the path more clearly. Don't have to find it in the dump of info.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use htaccess to this problem

If you dont have, make file .htaccess (with the dot in root) and write down

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_value short_open_tag 1
 </IfModule>
```

Good hosting providers does not provide the enter into php.ini

Comment: doesn't work. I Have added it to the existing htaccess in my laravel projevt folder !

Comment: Are you sure, that your server runs on Linux? htaccess is not functional on windows servers

Comment: 1. Vagrant homestead uses nginx, the .htaccess file is for cross-compatibility with apache when your app is deployed
2. It's a bad idea to change the php.ini as all other answers suggest, because all that's needed to screw up the changes is a `homestead destroy`
3. A more viable solution could be to conditionally set it at run-time `if (app()->environment() === "local) { ... }`, and set the php.ini correctly on your production servers

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue i solved it by opening **php.ini** file in **root** user mode otherwise you will not have permission to edit file....