# MacOS Laravel Valet increase memory_limit

Tags: php, laravel-valet

I try to increase the memory_limit of php with Laravel valet.

### What I see:

With **phpinfo()** I see:

- `memory_limit    128M`
- Configuration File (php.ini) Path    `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4`
- Loaded Configuration File `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini`
- Scan this dir for additional .ini
  files    `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d` Additional .ini files
  parsed   `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini,`
  `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini`

### What I already do

- I update **php.ini** and **php-memory-limit.ini** to edit the memory_limit from 128M to 256M: `memory_limit = 256M`
- Then I have run the following command: `valet restart`
- I also try to edit /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php-fpm.d/valet-fpm.conf to add `php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 256M`
- But after that the memory_limit stuck to 128M ( with phpinfo() )

*the following command return me 256M: `php -i | grep memory_limit`*

**Any idea how to increase this value ?**

Comment: I just modify this file , it works: `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found a solution but I didn't understand why it works, but not what I did before. If anyone has an explanation, I'm interested.

I edit `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php-fpm.d/valet-fpm.conf` and replace following line   `php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M`
With this line
`php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 256M`

Then I run the following command:

```sh
valet restart
brew services restart php@7.4
```

With just one of these two commands it doesn't work.
However `valet restart` is supposed to restart php, right?

Comment: Thank you for this! I don't understand why this value is determining the memory_limit either. I couldn't get those changes to be seen with either of those commands actually. I went into Activity Monitor and quit/force quit all php-fpm processes, then was able to see the changes.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the explanation. I've been dealing with this for weeks, not documented anywhere. I had the exact same problem with the exact same stack. Saving this for future reference.

Answer (score 10):

One solution worked with me, editing the file:

> /usr/local/etc/php/7.2/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini

And change the value `memory_limit`, save and run the command (to make sure it was changed):

`php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"`

Then, restart Valet:

`valet restart`

Comment: this should be the answer

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 6):

On Mac silicon it's lying there: `/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.1/conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini`

And make sure you restart valet next: `valet restart`

Answer (score 3):

Check the memory limit using

```
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
```

Then you can check the config file loaded

```
php --ini
```

Sometimes there are more than one, so please check all the config files.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Mac intl chip. And in my case file is /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php-fpm.d/www.conf
and further changes i did same as mentioned right answer.

Thank you so much for answer.

"I found a solution but I didn't understand why it works, but not what I did before. If anyone has an explanation, I'm interested.

I edit /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php-fpm.d/valet-fpm.conf and replace following line php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M
With this line
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 256M

Then I run the following command:

valet restart
brew services restart php@7.4
With just one of these two commands it doesn't work.
However valet restart is supposed to restart php, right?"