# Composer update hangs but composer install is running

Tags: laravel, macos, composer-php

I am trying to run composer update or if I tried to install any package for my site it hangs saying this

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

But If I try composer install it is working with

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
- Installing psr/log (1.1.2): Loading from cache
- Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.13.1): Loading from cache
- Installing phpoption/phpoption (1.6.0): Loading from cache
......
```

I am using Laravel Homestead with vagrant and virtualbox

Whats the problem and How to solve it

Answer (score 2):

composer is still hanging try to clear composer cache:

```
composer clear-cache
```

If these steps does not repair your composer then it's possible that the system does not have enough RAM memory available

Increase memory https://stackoverflow.com/a/44533437/3518053 or

Generate swap file .Try creating a swap file to provide more memory

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue a few times. Composer install is mostly working becuase it doesn't have to check every package for updates. To fix this a few options you can try :

- update composer to latest
- remove the complete vendor folder and run `composer update`
- increase ram memory (most times it fails because of this). Check out this Q [Composer update memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107400/composer-update-memory-limit)
- Check you `composer.json` file for unnecessary package depths, some packages require other packages wich can overload your cpu and ram.
- Try `composer update --prefer-dist`

Comment: memory allocation did it for me. In my case, I needed 4gb.