# Memory limit on composer installation

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, nginx

I have a cloud in the digital ocean where it has 1 GB of ram.
I need to install a docker, laravel, mysql, nginx environment, I found the laradock and installed it normally but when running the composer in the container I am returning a memory limit error.

Error running: composer install

```
root@b9864446a1e1:/var/www/site# composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 677388288) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 677388288) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52
```

Error when trying to change memory.

> WARNING: Your kernel does not support swap limit capabilities or the
>   cgroup is not mounted. Memory limited without swap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer update memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107400/composer-update-memory-limit)

Comment: no,when executing the update command the error below occurs!!! mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 266338304) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Package/Loader/ArrayLoader.php on line 241

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 266338304) (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Package/Loader/ArrayLoader.php on line 241

Comment: Are you running on VPS?

Comment: Yes, in the Digital Ocean a cloud of 1gb ram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be happening because the VPS runs out of memory and **has no Swap space enabled**.

```
free -m

total used free shared buffers cached
Mem:  xxxx xxx xxxx x x xxx
-/+ buffers/cache: xxx xxxx
Swap: 0 0 0
```

To enable the swap you can use for example:

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

You can make a permanent swap file following [this tutorial from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: The last command fails with the message `swapon: /var/swap.1: swapon failed: Operation not permitted`

Comment: jailshell: /bin/dd: Permission denied