# Unable to install Laravel on Server

Tags: php, laravel, server

I am trying to install laravel on my cloud hosting shared server using putty through Putty.

When I try to execute commands i get following error

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

> Installing laravel/laravel (v5.4.30)
>
> - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.4.30): Loading from cache Created project in /home1/repletub/skillforces/laravel
>
> > php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');" Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
> > dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 803209216) (tried to allocate 32
> bytes) in
> phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php
> on line 129

After looking for solutions over internet i found that, memory_limit property in php.ini must be set to -1.

So from cpanel i changed it for my domain. It still showed me the same error.

To cross-check i executed following sequence of commands , but here it does not reflect the changes.

```
php --ini

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.d/01-ioncube.ini,

cat /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc/php.ini

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 256M
```

Can anyone guide me resolving this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107400/composer-update-memory-limit

Comment: After change the php.ini you need to restart apache.

Comment: @Kevin
 php -d memory_limit=-1 /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer update

php -d memory_limit=512M /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer update

i executed these 2 commands. still the same issue

Comment: @STA No facility to restart the server on shared hosting. If u have any trick for that on jailshell please provide it.

Comment: You can check your `php.ini` update or not by create a page with data `<?php
phpinfo();

?>`

Comment: @STA it shows properly in <?php phpinfo();  ?> but not in SSH cmd in putty.