# Laravel elastic search returning allocated memory excceded error while installing

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

Am facing issue of allocated memory exceed while installing laravel elasti search by using below command

```
Composer install eleasticsearch/elasticsearch
```

Can any one please help me with same as I tried multiple options to do so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107400/composer-update-memory-limit

Comment: Hi @jewis I tried that part but it says composer is not known command when tried with php command it says could not open input file composer.

Comment: Maybe try running the commend on your computer and then upload it