# Trying to set PHP command line option produces weird output

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to work around the Composer memory limit issue, and using the answer from this question [Composer update memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107400/composer-update-memory-limit).

But this is what happens:

```
$ php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer require foo/bar

/usr/bin/env php -d allow_url_fopen=On -d detect_unicode=Off /usr/local/Cellar/composer/1.0.0-alpha8/libexec/composer.phar $*
```

What is going on here?

I don't want a fix to the Composer problem, I've found another way to deal with that. My question is specifically about what this output means and why it's happening.

Comment: You can start by running `which php` and checking whatever comes out. Is it a shell script or a binary file?

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but it seems you have a very ancient composer release. Try updating, maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by "what is going on here"? Anything not working as expected?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes, it's not working as expected -- see the other question I linked to! It should run `composer require foo/bar` but with the memory limit adjusted. Instead I get mysterious output that looks like it's from the innards of PHP!