# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes composer update

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I want to run the command composer update to my Laravel project by running the below command.

```
composer update
```

When I try to run composer require I am getting the out of memory error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
```

Comment: Did you try adding COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 to your environment?

Comment: Have you read last sentence you've posted here and tried suggested `php -d memory_limit=-1 composer update`?

Comment: It does seem weird that composer would use over 1.6GB of memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Composer update memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107400/composer-update-memory-limit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run

```
which composer
```

This will give you the path to composer like "/usr/bin/composer"

Then use that path in the command below to overcome the memory limit using the php flag for no memory limit, like this:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/bin/composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update
```

That temporarily sets the composer memory limit to unlimited.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.